# Animation Listerner not responding with Animatorset

Tags: java, android

I am trying to have an animation begin after another another one ends. I am using animation property and I define the objects as "AnimatorSet." The problem is that the first animation begins without a problem but the second one never starts.

```
public void moveGround() {

        ImageView ground = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ground);
        ImageView ground2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ground2);
        final AnimatorSet moveGround = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.ground_move);
        final Animator moveGround2 = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(this, R.animator.ground_move2);
        moveGround2.setTarget(ground2);
        moveGround.setTarget(ground);
        moveGround.start();

        moveGround.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                moveGround2.start();
            }
        });


    }
```

EDIT: I have also tried to start the first animation after the animation listener ends: same results.

EDIT 2: XML files

ground_move.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="2000"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:valueFrom="2000"
        android:valueTo="-2000"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        />

</set>
```

ground_move2.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="2000"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:valueFrom="2000"
        android:valueTo="-2000"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

Comment: Check the others methods (`onAnimationCancel(), onAnimationPause(), onAnimationRepeat(), onAnimationResume()`), print a log, maybe is being paused somewhere else.

Comment: Ah yes, so it starts up when I try it with "onAnimationStart()." Why isn't it firing up the other methods?

Comment: add the xml files s:

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I added the xml files. Thanks agian

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
moveGround.setTarget(ground);
moveGround.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
        moveGround2.start();
    }
});
moveGround.start();
```

(Note how we first add the listener, then start the animation) If this doesn't works, try set a limited time: `moveGround.setDuration(sometime);` before start it to check if effectively is finishing your animation.

**UPDATE**

After you added the xml files, I see that you have the `android:repeatCount="infinite"` and `android:repeatMode="restart"`, try to remove them or set `android:repeatCount=0` and check if your listener is properly fired.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I tried this but it isn't working neither. I also added the setDuration and it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Yes! the animation fires up after I removed the repeatCount(OR set it = 0) and when I remove the repeatMode as you suggested. How can I get the first one to loop back again?

Comment: that's a good question, a workaround is to restart your animation in a new listener in your second animator object